# Combobox autocomplete automatically choose the top item of sugesstion list when press enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I already used jquery combobox autocomplete like on the demo below.

> [jquery combobox autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox)

How to make jquery combobox autocomplete automaticly choose the top item of sugesstion when i press the enter button?

So user doesnt need to entered the full text..
thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An extension for the autocomplete plugin that automatically selects the first item. Just set the selectFirst option to true:

```
$('#auto').autocomplete({
      selectFirst: true
});
```

**[Check This FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DaxHb/)**

http://github.com/scottgonzalez/jquery-ui-extensions/blob/master/autocomplete/jquery.ui.autocomplete.selectFirst.js

Comment: i must import the extension first?

Comment: it works but i have style problem now...
in some case the width of suggestion area bigger than usual...

Do you know about this?

Comment: you have fix width given to combo box nothing other solution.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17130/discussion-between-user1511798-and-user108)

Comment: sorry sir...i dont know why i cant write in chat room.
actually i already define the width like this...any other solution?
$($('.ui-combobox-input')[0]).css('width', '500px');